# phpmyadmin access denied error

Tags: 16.04, gnome, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using Ubuntu Gnome. [phpmyadmin access denied error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jBj.png)Whenever i try to open phpmyadmin it prompts the following error:
Error: MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Find the error screenshot attached. Any suggestions regarding how to solve this would be of great help

Comment: PHPMyAdmin uses the server name from `config.inc.php`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Yes,the configuration settings haven't been modified since installation

Comment: Can you log into MySQL from the command line using the same username, password and server?

Comment: can you tell me how to do the same from the terminal?

Comment: `mysql -u [USERNAME] -h [SERVER] -p`. You will be prompted for the password.

Comment: It says mysql isn't installed. The exact information that it prompts upon entering the command mysql -u root -h localhost -p is The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.7
 * mariadb-client-core-10.0
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

Comment: Then install `mysql-client`. It is not `mysql-server` which is a large and much more complicated beast.

Comment: But i got the access denied error just now. I have used it many times till now. But  i got the error just this time.

Comment: Yes, so *something* must have changed. We're trying to find out what.

Comment: Yes,i've installed mysql-client and then run the command mysql -u root -h localhost -p and then upon typing the password it prompted the following error
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) @Jos

Comment: Ah. Replace localhost by the address of the server that the website runs on. You see, to the PHPMyAdmin software running on the website, "localhost" means the web server; to you, "localhost" means the computer in front of you.

Comment: Yes,i 've repalced localhost with localhost:3306 the port on which MySQL Server is running. But still the issue persists

Comment: Yes, now i could log into the MySQL from the commandline.. But still could not open phpmyadmin via localhost in the browser @Jos